# Self signing jar file, doesn't find JarSigner class

Tags: java, keytool, jarsigner, jar-signing

I'm trying to sign my java applet.
I ran the following lines to create a cert:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias ben
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias ben
```

up to here everything works well. It requires a password and some details and creates the MyKeyStore file.

Then I run this line:

```
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore nnis.jar ben
```

But all it does is tell me:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.security.tools.JarSigner
```

the file tools.jar (in which the JarSigner.class exists) is in the "PATH", and just to be sure, I also copied it to the local dir from which I run the jarsigner command.

What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate any advice - to solve the problem or bypassing it.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"*  Start with.. *"I put the file tools.jar (in which the JarSigner.class exists) in the same directory of which I ran the commands."*  Don't do that.  Leave the components of the JRE where they were installed and add that place to the path.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I also added the dir to the path, but it didn't help (I edited the question so it will be clear...)

Comment: Forget about the PATH. JAR files are not searched for on the PATH, but on the CLASSPATH, or, as in this case, directly in the install directory of the JDK or JRE. Just put the entire JDK or JRE back how it was before you started fiddling around pointlessly with it. Reinstall it if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Jarsigner.exe searches for tools.jar relative to its own location. In the JDK, they are located in:

```
<jdk-install-folder>\bin\jarsigner.exe
<jdk-install-folder>\lib\tools.jar
```

As long as you maintain the same relative folder structure, it should find the JarSigner class. For example if your jarsigner.exe is in **C:\Temp\YourFolder\jarsigner.exe**, you should put the tools.jar in **C:\Temp\lib\tools.jar**.